# Google Checkout. Show shipping rates before logging in possible?

Tags: html, e-commerce, google-checkout

I am trying to integrate google checkout with my current site.  I am calculating the shipping on my end, before passing it to google checkout.  The problem is, when a person click the "google checkout" button, it takes them to google checkout but it does not show the shipping.  It actually states it will be calculated on next step.  In the next step it actually shows a drop down with the ONE option for shipping that I passed, which is a flat rate..

The problem is, to get to the next step you have to enter a credit card.  Also, my shop has the shipping shown in the cart, so it would seem confusing to go to checkout and have a price without shipping.

Here is the test code I am using right now to see if I can get it to show shipping before logging in (sample it here: http://sensenich.bythepixel.com/test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Site Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST"
      action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/468503062558352"
      accept-charset="utf-8">


  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Peanut Butter"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="Chunky peanut butter."/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="3.99"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="USD"/>

<input type="hidden"
  name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.name"
  value="UPS Next Day Air"/>
<input type="hidden"
  name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.price"
  value="20.00"/>
<input type="hidden"
  name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.shipping-methods.flat-rate-shipping-1.price.currency"
  value="USD"/>


  <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" />

  <!-- Button code -->
  <input type="image"
    name="Google Checkout"
    alt="Fast checkout through Google"
    src="http://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=468503062558352&w=180&h=46&style=white&variant=text&loc=en_US"
    height="46"
    width="180" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can calculate shipping values on your end, which sounds pretty likely if you only have a single flat rate:

- Remove Checkout's shipping values to disable shipping calculations on that end.
- Calculate shipping costs yourself and pass it along as a "product."

Checkout won't automatically assume it's a digital-delivery sale and omit shipping address or anything, it will just chug along assuming there's no shipping cost (...test this first, it's been a while since I used Checkout).

If there are other variables in orbit, like state tax rates or discounts/coupons that need to be handled before shipping costs are set, this might not be so ideal.

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge this is impossible.